# Check for air update more than once

Tags: actionscript-3, air, auto-update, flash-cs6

When I start my program I run my initialize() and it checks for update, if there is an update it prompts nicely, and docks to the lower part of my window if the user clicks "not now"

```
function initiate(){
    newest_txt.text = "";
    version_txt.text = appXML.ns::versionNumber;
    appUpdater.initialize();
    ...
```

everything works fine, *once*

I have a timer that calls for updates every 10 seconds

```
function realoadTemplates(e){
    loadTemplates();
    appUpdater.initialize();
}
```

but this does not check for updates, it doesn't even go into my `function onUpdate(event){` like it does when called the first time.

i've tried calling `appUpdater.checkNow();`, `appUpdater.checkForUpdate ()` and `appUpdater.downloadUpdate()` I've also tried setting `appUpdater = null` and then redefining it, but that doesn't do anything either.

what do I have to do to check for updates more than once?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I now made a seperate xml checker for the update-app xml, a seperate timer for the update and only initialize if there is an update ready.

```
function newVerCheckTime(e){
    randomNumber1000= Math.round(Math.random()*1000)
    versionLoad.load(new URLRequest(webRoot+"update/update-app.xml"+"?    randomLink="+randomNumber1000));
}

function loadVersion(event){
    var versionLoaderForUpdate:XML = new XML(event.target.data);
    var versionOfThis:Namespace = versionLoaderForUpdate.namespace();
    if(versionLoaderForUpdate.versionOfThis::versionNumber>appXML.ns::versionNumber){
        appUpdater.initialize();
    }
}
```

and this works!